# Prove that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty} {a^x * x^p} = 0$ with $0<a<1, p>0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I've tried to change variable:

y = $a^x$ and $x = \log_a y $

$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty} {a^x * x^p} = \lim\limits_{y \rightarrow 0} {y * p * \log_a y}$

I think $\log_a y$ doesn't exist for y$\rightarrow0$ so the result of the limit is $0$. Is it correct? I need to prove this only using variable changing.

Comment: Suppose $x=\log_a y$. Then $x^p=(\log_a y)^p \neq \log_a y^p$.

Comment: I tried that like i wrote in the post @zugzug

Comment: You have $p \log_a y$, which appears to be a simplification of $\log_a y^p$. While this simplification is correct, it is not correct to use it in the problem since you really have $(\log_a y)^p.$ Taking the quantity of a log function to the $p$ is not the same as taking log of a number to the $p$.

Answer (score 2):

Take

$$\log\left(a^x x^p\right) = x \log a + p\log x.$$

Since $0 < a < 1$, the first term is negative. However, $x$ grows much faster than $\log x$, so the above sum converges to $-\infty$. Therefore the original sequence must converge to zero.